# ArgoUML Operations

Tags: uml, argouml

I have created an ERD (Entity-Relationship Diagram) using ArgoUML and I wish to create two operations within a class which both have a `void` return type.  However, I am only able to create one operation which returns a `void` type.

For example:

[image]

I am able to set the return type of `bookInitial()` to `void` but whenever I try to set the return type of `bookFollowUp()` to `void`, the option is not available.

Having checked with other classes in the project, it would appear that each class only allows one object to have a `void` return type - is this true for all classes?

Is there is there a way to assign the `void` return type to more than one operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArgoUML is a UML modeling tool, so it doesn't have E-R diagrams.  You were probably working with UML Class Diagrams.

What version of ArgoUML are you using?  If that really doesn't work, and you're running the latest version (0.32.2), it sounds like a bug which should be reported at http://argouml.tigris.org/project_bugs.html

Comment: Yes, I meant that I am using the UML's class diagrams in order to create an ERD.  It is only for my personal reference, however, I am modelling a system that I will need to implement at some point in the future and therefore need to work out exactly how the different elements (classes) will interact with one another.  I am also using `v0.32.2`.  I may report it as a bug if I am unsuccessful in resolving the issue myself.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I have no problem in creating two operations that return void (with Argo v.0.24). In fact, when adding new operations they are created as returning void by default